# como hacer CRUD para cada formulario en c#?

Tags: c#, mysql, crud

Hola estoy tratando de hacer mi primer programa (UN PUNTO DE  VENTA)
y de verdad que necesito de su ayuda.

Lo que quiero saber si debo hacer todos los CRUD de cada formulario en una sola clases o si cada CRUD debe ir en clases diferente? ojo no estoy trabajando con "capas"

En caso de que sea un CRUD por clase, por favor me dicen como se hace.
y a la vez me gustaría saber como se llama la fomar de trabajar en c# cuando
no se trabaja con capas

En caso de que sea un CRUD por clase, por favor me dicen como se hace.
y a la vez me gustaría saber como se llama la fomar de trabajar en c# cuando
no se trabaja con capas

```
   public void Abrir_conexion()
    {
        con = new SqlConnection("Data Source =.; Initial Catalog = PruebaProcedimiento; Integrated Security = True");
        con.Open();
    }

   
    public void Cerrar_conexion()
    {
        con.Close();
    }

    // LLENANDO UN DATAGRIDVIEW..............................................
    public void Llenando_datagrid( DataGridView datgrid )
    {
        try {

            Abrir_conexion();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("Alumno",con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            dt = new DataTable();
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
          
            Cerrar_conexion();
            datgrid.DataSource = dt;
                         
        }          
            catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No se lleno el dataGrid" + ex).ToString();
        }
              
    }

    //GUARDAR..............................................
    public string guardar(string nombre,string apellido,int edad)
    {
       string mensaje = "Nuevo estudiante agregado";

        try
        {
            Abrir_conexion();
      
        cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_Guardar", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
       
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombre", nombre).ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Apellido", apellido).ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Edad", Convert.ToInt32(edad));
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        Cerrar_conexion();
        }
        
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error RICKY" + ex).ToString();
        }

           return mensaje;        
    }

    // Validar registro al insertarlo..............................................

    public int validar(string nombre)
        {
           int cont=0;

        try
        {
            Abrir_conexion();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_Validar", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@validar", nombre).ToString();

            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                cont++;
            }

            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            Cerrar_conexion();
        
        }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error Ricky no valido correctamente!" + ex).ToString();

        }
           return cont;

        }


    //ELIMINAR..............................................

    public int  Eliminar(string nombre)
    {

        int cont = 0;

        try {

            Abrir_conexion();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_Eliminar",con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombre",nombre);
            cont = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Pongo una variable entera (cont) porque ahi me devuelve un uno, o un cero 
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            Cerrar_conexion();
            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
         MessageBox.Show("Error RICKY no se ELIMINO el registro" + ex).ToString();
        }
        return cont;
    }
    //ACTUALIZAR..............................................

    public string Actualizar(string nombre, string apellido, int edad, string actualizar )
    { string mensaje = "Datos actualizado correctamente!";
        try
        { Abrir_conexion();
                
        cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_Actulizar", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombre", nombre).ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Apellido",apellido).ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Edad", Convert.ToInt32(edad)).ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@actualizar", actualizar).ToString();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        Cerrar_conexion();

        }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error RICKY no se ACTUALIZO el registro" + ex).ToString();
        }

        return mensaje;
    }
            
    // BUSCAR..............................................
    public void Buscar ( string txtbuscar, DataGridView data)
    {
        try
        {
         

        Abrir_conexion();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("Buscar", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filtro", txtbuscar).ToString();
                   
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        data.DataSource = dt;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Cerrar_conexion();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error RICKY no se encontro  registro" + ex).ToString();

        }

       
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo mejor es que trabajes en clases por separado para cada funcionalidad. Te recomiendo que le des un mirada a [Los principios SOLID](https://medium.com/@ger86/los-5-principios-solid-68d697984abd), no estoy seguro que exista un nombre como tal a la forma de trabajar sin en capas, pero si puedo decirte que estarás entrenando el error y tú código sera un poco menos sencillo de mantener.

Comment: Entonces quiere  decir  que tengo que hacer una conexión a cada clase? Me gustaría utilizar una  sola conexión para a si no tener que hacer una conexión a cada clase. si se puede, por favor dígame como se hace

Comment: Deberías tener la menor cantidad de tiempo posible abierta la conexión. Para eso utiliza el patrón Repository.

Comment: Deberías tener la menor cantidad de tiempo posible abierta la conexión. Para eso utiliza el patrón Repository.

Crea una clase que contenga la lógica de conexión y extracción de datos. ejemplo RegistrosRepository, allí se encuentra la extracción de la información(CRUD de registros).

Luego en el visual haces una instancia de la clase para llenar RegistroRepository para llenar el DataGrid.
´
data.DataSource = registroRepository.Buscar("texto a buscar");

Comment: @AdersonRangel Por favor lee [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @Gabitohh lo intente y no me salio el código. Y las ediciones tiene un limite y tiempo